# How to cache array of Doubles in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

The following code

```
let cache = NSCache<NSString, [Double]>()
```

gives me the error:

```
'NSCache' requires that '[Double]' be a class type
```

How can I cache an **array of Doubles** using `String` as the key?

Comment: As already mentioned by Matt you will need to save your Double array as a NSArray of NSNumber.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by others, NSCache is an objC type and will only work with NSObject subclasses. You can use type bridging into NSArray for this.

```
let cache = NSCache<NSString, NSArray>()
let doubleArray: [Double] = [2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
cache.setObject(doubleArray as NSArray, forKey: "key")

// ...

if let doubleArray = cache.object(forKey: "key") as? [Double] {
    // Got my array back
}
```

Answer (score 3):

NSCache is in the Cocoa Objective-C world so you have to play by Cocoa Objective-C rules. You could declare `cache` as an `NSCache<NSString, NSArray>`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can to do

```
let cache = NSCache<NSString,NSArray>()

cache.setObject([NSNumber.init(value: 2.0),NSNumber.init(value: 3.0)], forKey: "value1")

print(cache.object(forKey: "value1")!)
```